# Correct review action for correct "low-quality" answers that could use elaboration

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

While going through the low-quality answer queue, I run into a lot of answer that address the question, have a correct solution, but don't provide much context or an explanation.

When I encounter these, I usually leave a comment and skip them in the queue. For example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28503722/129032
- [How to reverse a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503215/how-to-reverse-a-text-file/28503749#28503749)
- [Easy way to set javascript object multilevel property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424226/easy-way-to-set-javascript-object-multilevel-property/28503332#28503332)

The options in the queue are:

- "Looks OK"

  - I suppose they do, but only OK
- "Edit"

  - I could take the code and explain it, but that seems like a significant change to someone's answer and a great opportunity to misinterpret and misrepresent their solution
- "Recommend Deletion"

  - No, it's a perfectly correct answer, it would just be better with more detail.
- "Skip"

  - What I've mostly been doing, but it seems wrong, since it leaves the answer in the queue.

What is the appropriate review action for a correct but terse answer? What's the best way to ask the poster for elaboration? Is this common enough that it has a button (or should have a button, or has been discussed before)?